# SQL Sum of Payments

Tags: mysql

I have two `MYSQL` tables:

1. users: ID, payment, date of payment
2. payments: ID, userID, amount, date of payment

Payment in table 1 is supposed to be the aggregate of all payments of that user from table  and date of payment the date of the last payment of a user.

`users.payment` should be the sum of `payments.userID`. So every-time a payment is recorded in table `payments`, `users.payment` is updated and `users.date` of payment is updated to the latest `payments.date` of payment

As a total SQL-newbie I would like to know how I can achieve that users.payment is the sum of payments.amount and gets updated automatically for each new insertion into the payments table.

Comment: *Payment in table 1 is supposed to be the aggregate of all payments of that user from table and date of payment the date of the last payment of a user*. Can you make this little more clear.

Comment: it's generally considered bad practice to store derived data

Comment: @Sinto I'm guessing what he means is that every x hours the sum of a userID gets calculated from the payments table and the users table gets updated afterwards with the amount and the timestamp.

Comment: @Sinto: users.payment should be the sum of payments.payment (for the respective userID). So everytime a payment is recorded in table "payments", users.payment is updated and users.date of payment is updated to the latest payments.date of payment

Comment: Have you tried to come up with a solution? By attempting to get things done yourself first, you can gain a feel for how MySQL actually works and gain experience. As a hint I'd suggest to split up the task into multiple statements to get that done.

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the info. I am supposed to display the tables via the DatatTables jQuery plugin. So I guess I should calculate the sums there and not in the database?

Comment: You would normally derive the data in a query